# i want to put my actual logic in it, for which i am getting filenot found exception

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, ant, gradle-plugin

I created a custom plugin using `gradlew init --> selected plugin option`. This created all the required dir structure and and one plugingroovy file which has the custom plugin class implementing Plugin interface and an apply() method. I successfully built and published it to my local maven reposistory using "gradlew publishToMavenLocal" and imported that plugin in other gradle projects Like below. When i tried to build the other project it printed "Hello World" perfectly.

Now I want to put my actual logic in it, for which I am getting filenot found exception. I kept the file under src/main/resources/coco.gradle and built the jar. Opened the jar file with 7zip ad also verified, plugin jar has the coco.gradle in it.

```
package com.jink.test
import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.gradle.api.tasks.InputFile
import org.gradle.api.tasks.OutputFile

class FileDiffPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {

        project.tasks.create('javaCoco') {
           
           def file = new File('src/main/resources/coco.gradle')
           ant.loadfile(srcFile: file , property: file.name)

           
           println "Hello World"
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting filenotfound exception as it trying to locate that file in the directory of the project from where I am running but not from the jar.

```
* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.tomgregory.file-diff', version: '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT']
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.jinka.test'.
   > E:\jinka\testgradle\src\main\resources\coco.gradle doesn't exist
```

coco.gradle has below code

```
apply plugin: "jacoco"
allprojects {
jacoco {
toolVersion = "0.8.2"
}
test {
jacoco {
destinationFile = file("$buildDir/../target/jacoco.exec")
}

jacocotestReport {
reports{
     true xml.enabled
     true html.enabled
}
}
}
```

I want to enclose the above jacoco gradle code within one custom plugin and ask teams to use that custom plugin instead of the entire code in build.gradle or the file.

Comment: `E:\jinka\testgradle\src\main\resources\coco.gradle doesn't exist`

Comment: Its there within jar, not sure why it is trying to locate that file from the local filesystem.

Comment: Can somebody help me on how to wrap jacoco plugin aloong with its tasks like testReport etc into custom plugin